# Helper "fields_for" not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, haml, helper, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm using nested attributes, but the fields aren't loaded in my view.
Someone know what I missing?

**Rails 3.1, Ruby 1.9.2**

Model 1:

```
class Traditions::Material < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :material_asset, :dependent => :destroy
  validates_presence_of :title
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :material_asset
end
```

Model 2:

```
class Traditions::MaterialAsset < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :material
  has_attached_file :asset
  validates_attachment_presence :asset
end
```

View (HAML):

```
= form_for @material, :html => {:class => 'form', :multipart => true} do |f|
    = errors_for @material

    .field
        = f.label :title
        = f.text_field :title

    .field
        = f.label :description
        = f.text_area :description, :rows => 5

    .field
        = f.fields_for :material_asset do |ma|
            = ma.label :asset
            = ma.file_field :asset

    .buttonrow
        = f.submit 'Save'
```

Result HTML (part):

```
<div class='field'></div>
<div class='buttonrow'>
  <input name="commit" type="submit" value="Save" />
</div>
```

In above, `div.field` is empty.

Comment: Sidenote: You don't need to specify multipart true in Rails 3.1. It's automatically added when you've a file field in your form.

Comment: It's so cool. Thanks for the tip! :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I stumbled across this from your [rails issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/1204), which appears to be not building the nested resource in your `new` action.

Are you calling `build_material_asset` in your controller? That could explain why the fields aren't getting rendered. If the nested object is `nil`, there are no object to render fields for.

Try something like this:

```
class MaterialsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @material = Traditions::Material.new
    @material.build_material_asset
  end
end
```

Comment: This definitely sounds like the most likely case.

Comment: Great! I was using a form partial on an additional page on my website but the fields_for fields were missing and it was completely baffling me...... until I found this thread. Problem solved, thanks.

Comment: Previously added as an edit with typos, but for reference I put it here again: when using `has_many` you have to build an instance using `@material.material_assets.build`

Answer (score 3):

fields_for has new syntax.

```
= fields_for :plan, @plan do |builder| ...
```

in controller (action new) :

```
@plan = Parent.plans.new
```

read more here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for

Comment: Why the hell should I have a downvote if I'm giving a valid information?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot check, but something like this?

```
- form_for @material, :html => {:class => 'form', :multipart => true} do |f|
    = errors_for @material

    #field
        = f.label :title
        = f.text_field :title

    #field
        = f.label :description
        = f.text_area :description, :rows => 5

    #field
        - f.fields_for :material_asset do |ma|
            = ma.label :asset
            = ma.file_field :asset

    .buttonrow
        = f.submit 'Save'
```

The problem is that you have nested `=`. You should use `-` for the outer iterations. Also, are you sure that `.field` works? Isn't it supposed to be `#field`?

Comment: `=` is right, you can see here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for

But I think its not matter. Anyway I tested both and still not working.

Comment: Your link is for erb, but you are writing in haml. Do you really get the result that you posted?

Comment: Yep, is too strange, exactly this

Comment: `f.fields_for :material_asset` is returning 0 objects, didn't loop.